# Automapper: mapping a single member on type object to Icollection of object

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to map an individual object into a field that is an ICollection of the object using automapper, an example layout is as such...

```
public class BarDto {
    public int id {get;set;}
    public int name {get;set;}
    public ICollection<ExampleObject> FooCollection {get;set;}
}

public class Bar {
    public int id {get;set;}
    public int name {get;set;}
    public ExampleObject Foo {get;set;}
}


Mapper.CreateMap<BarDto, Bar>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.FooCollection, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Foo));
```

Is there anyway of converting src.foo into a list etc to be accepted as ICollection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Bar, BarDto>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.FooCollection, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => new List<ExampleObject>() { src.Foo } ));
```

Or you can realize your own `ValueResolver<ExampleObject, List<ExampleObject>>`

and do something like:

```
public class ExampleResolver: ValueResolver<ExampleObject, List<ExampleObject>>
{
    protected override List<ExampleObject> ResolveCore(ExampleObject source)
    {
        return new List<ExampleObject>() { source };
    }
}
```

and then:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<BarDto, Bar>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.FooCollection, opts => opts.ResolveUsing<ExampleResolver>());
```

Second approach usually is used in more complicated cases, but you can select any approach you wish.

Hope, it helps.

Comment: The ValueResolver works :) Cheers, I would of thought the first example would of worked too but falls over for some reason, maybe something to do with further/deeper maps on the object.

Comment: I guess that first example does not work because of wrong order of types in `<T1,T2>`. Got fixed.

Comment: Anyway, glad to help :)

Comment: Also a type converter could work here, if the Thing -> Collection<Thing> happens many places.